# "Cannot perform start session" when using SSM Agent port forwarding

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-ssm

I'm trying to do port forwarding with the AWS SSM Agent using the following command:

```
aws ssm start-session --target i-12345ab123a12ab12 --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSession --parameters "portNumber"=["80"],"localPortNumber"=["80"]
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot perform start session: invalid argument
```

The command then bombs out and I'm returned to the command line.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first confirmed that the requested port was open on my EC2 instance using

```
lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

I then returned to my local machine and ran, as per the question:

```
aws ssm start-session --target i-12345ab123a12ab12 --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSession --parameters "portNumber"=["80"],"localPortNumber"=["80"]
```

Then I got the error!!!

I realized SSM Agent is not actually packaged with the AWS CLI tools.  I upgraded AWS CLI for the heck of it, but more importantly - re-installed SSM Agent for the latest version.

Then everything worked :)

The AWS documentation containing the steps to install the SSM Agent plugin can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-install-plugin.html)